# armv7s three20 xcode 4.5

Tags: three20, ios6, xcode4.5

how can I use `three20` with the new `xcode 4.5`?

I got this message :

```
(null): Symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go into the framework settings, and change the target from armv6/armv7 to "armv7 armv7s" and compile again.

Comment: That's what I thought too. I keep trying to do that under "Architectures" but Xcode changes it right back on me <!>. If I expand that and change "Any iOS SDK" to Standard (arm7, arm7s), it appears to stay put though. Interesting.

Comment: Did you change in both project and target settings?

Comment: Only in project. Target does not have any explicit settings, thus the project settings clearly show through properly. The only way I could fix it was to change "Any iOS SDK" to Standard, and then it worked. Very weird.

Comment: We had to change it to "armv7" only because one of our frameworks was not compiled with armv7s, and setting it to armv7 worked. I will test sometime to see if setting it by hand works in another project.